# Which are the different types of Exception occurred in performing LINQ Operation?

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I want some help related Exception. I don't know ,which are the different types of exception occurred when we perform LINQ operation. Here is the code:

```
    public IPagedList<Party> GetParties(int page = 0, int take = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var PartyCollection = from e in db.Parties.OrderBy(e => e.Name)  
                                       where (e.IsDeleted == false || e.IsDeleted == null )
                                       select e;
            return PartyCollection.ToCustomPagedList(page, take);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

- Which type of exception will be occurred?
- How can I catch this exception?
- Which are the specific exception occurred & how to handle it catch block?

Comment: Any kind of exception can occur. You are already catching all managed exceptions (that can be caught), but rethrowing them. And if you don't know how to handle a specific exception, why do you want to keep running?

Comment: Look at MSDN if you want to know if a method can raise an exception. For example [`Queryable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx): **Exceptions**
`ArgumentNullException` if source or keySelector is null.

Answer (score 1):

When you search MSDN (for instance [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)), there is a list of exceptions that can be thrown, plus when that happens.

Note that in MSDN the extension method syntax is used.

Most (all?) methods throw an ArgumentNullException when the input-list is null. Other exceptions can occur, in "expected" places like an InvalidCastException when a `Cast<T>()` fails.

Of course any other exceptions could occur, just like any other code when memory is full, when the database doesn't react timely, etc.

Comment: Thanks .What are the specific or Major exception occurred.When we performing operation.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link, this will tell you what kind of problem you face in LINQ query and also the exception which occurs when that problem faced:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx

I hope it will help you.. :)